# Load js and css files in master page dynamic

Tags: asp.net

i have an master page and i use it in a aspx page, when i press a button i want to load some javascript files and css files and load a user control to my page, so i am doing this:

```
ContentPlaceHolder headContent = (ContentPlaceHolder)this.Page.Master.FindControl("headerContent");

HtmlGenericControl control = new HtmlGenericControl();
control.TagName = "script";
control.Attributes.Add("type", "text/javascript");
control.Attributes.Add("src", ResolveUrl("Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"));

headContent.Controls.Add(control);
```

all right, but if i load some plugins they dont work.
im loading this in user control oninit function.

i have a placeholder in master page head.

Comment: Have you looked at metaplaceholder?

Comment: no, never listen about this

Answer (score 1):

Instead of manually creating script tag, just call the useful [RegisterClientScriptInclude](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2552td66%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). It is easier. So change your code to following:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude("jQuery", "Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js");
```

or If your going to resolve url, do this:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude("jQuery", ResolveUrl("Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"));
```